# Excel Sheet-specific Cell Function running in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to take an equation I have in a cell and have it only run at the push of a button in a UserForm in VBA. The goal of this equation is to only count the amount of withdraws from a specific account only within the last three months before averaging the amount to a $/month.

The ComboBox in the VBA code selects the sheet that handles this branch, with Engineering Experts being an account name.

The cell formula is below:

```
=(SUMIFS(D:D,B:B,">="&(EDATE(TODAY(),-3)),B:B,"<="&TODAY(),E:E,"Engineering Experts"))/(-3)
```

In VBA the best I could come up with is as follows:

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

If ComboBox1.Value = "West Branch" Then
Me.TextBox1.Text = CStr(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("West Branch").Application.Evaluate("(SUMIFS(D:D,B:B,"">=""&(EDATE(TODAY(),-3)),B:B,""<=""&TODAY(),E:E,""Engineering Experts""))/(-3))"))

End If

End Sub
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: I don't think the `.Application` should be in there. If you want to evaluate the formula against a specific sheet, you should be using [`Worksheet.Evaluate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.evaluate).

Comment: I think there might be an extra parentheses at the end as well.

Comment: @BigBen I'm afraid that returns the same Error 2015. In the cell itself the formula works as intended.

Comment: Did you remove the extra parenthesis at the end? Should be `(-3)`, not `(-3))`.

Comment: I just did. It returns Run-Time Error 438: Object  doesn't support this property or method.

Comment: Using the .Application gives me zeros, but no errors.

Comment: Change `Sheets` to `Worksheets`.

Answer (score 0):

Summarizing the issues:

- You want to use [`Worksheet.Evaluate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.evaluate) to evaluate the formula against a specific worksheet. So remove the `.Application` and change `Sheets` to `Worksheets`.
- You have an extra parenthesis at the end: `(-3))` should be `(-3)`.